# How to sign an ethereum transaction with metamask

Tags: ethereum

I am currently sending transactions with this code:

```
      const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("ropsten", {
        infura:
          "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/ee11be9f1d1c43199618db4a7b22aa79",
      });

      const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);
      const account = signer.connect(provider);
      const uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
        ropstenUniswapContract,
        [
          "function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)",
        ],
        account
      );
      const gasCost = ethers.BigNumber.from((+gasPrice/10) * Math.pow(10, 9));
      console.log('Computed gas cost ->', gasCost);

      const tx = await uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens(
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        to,
        deadline,
        { value, gasPrice: gasCost }
      );

      // Transaction Hash and Block
      setTransactionHash(tx.hash);
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      console.log(receipt);
```

My question is:

How can I make MetaMask sign the transaction on my behalf instead of supplying my private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction signing is abstracted away with web3.js or [Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/). You can directly connect your Ethers.js to MetaMask provider (`windows.ethereum`) in in-page JavaScript code.

[An example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67836760/315168).

Answer (score 0):

Your (browser-facing) app can communicate with the MetaMask browser extension using the [Ethereum Provider API](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html).

Speficically the [eth_sendTransaction](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html) method passing it the `data` field (specifying which function in your contract you want to execute, as well as the passed argument values), along with other params such as the `sender` address.

If you're new to MetaMask, just a quick note: To get the user's list of addresses, you need to call the [eth_requestAccounts](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask) method.