# How to connect ethers.js to Metamask - await is only valid in async function error

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask, ethers.js

I'm trying to connect to Metamask using ethers.js.

However, all the solution I found keep returning this error

"await is only valid in async function"

Was there a recent change in Javascript syntax that affects await?

[How to connect ethers.js with metamask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785630/how-to-connect-ethers-js-with-metamask)

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
// Prompt user for account connections
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());
```

[how to connect metamask with ethers.js and fetch balance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296594/how-to-connect-metamask-with-ethers-js-and-fetch-balance)

```
await window.ethereum.enable();
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(smartContractAddress, abi, provider);
balance = await contract.getBalance("0x7C76C63DB86bfB5437f7426F4C37b15098Bb81da");
```

Comment: Since `await` was introduced, it has only been allowed in `async` functions, except much more recently in the top level of a module.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with ethers... promises, async, and await are core to how all of javascript works...

Answer (score 0):

You should put `await` in `async function` to work, like this:

```
async function connectToMetamask(){
   const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
   // Prompt user for account connections
   await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
   const signer = provider.getSigner();
   console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());
}
```